# In $\mathbb{Z}$ , let $a$ be a group element that has infinite order. Find all generators of $\langle a\rangle.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Since $a$ has infinite order, that means that there does not exist a positive integer $n$ such that $a^{n}=e$. I know that $1$ and $-1$ are the generators of $\mathbb{Z}$, and so they are the generators of $\langle a\rangle$. Is that it, or am I missing something?

Comment: $1$ and $-1$ may not be contained in $\langle a\rangle$. Try a particular example: what are the generators of $\langle 2\rangle=2\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: $2$ and $-2$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The same idea works for general $a$.

Comment: okay, that makes sense

Comment: Every such $\langle a\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ as a group, so you can definitively say what the generators are if you understand the generators of $\mathbb Z$.